# debugging webpack 2 generated bundles

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have a very simple hello world ES5 application https://github.com/rohans84/webpack-demo where I am trying to get some basic webpack 2 development.

After enabling sourcemaps for my webpack-dev-server build, I can see sourcemaps in Chrome DevTools under webpack:// section for my underlying code. However, the breakpoints I set there do not seem to work.

Is there additional configuration required to enable debugging and honoring of breakpoints? What is the point of sourcemaps if you cannot set breakpoints of your underlying code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145) at the moment. Best you can do is to break and get the correct line in the sourcemap, but stepping through will not work on Chrome and FF, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer to those interested. I was using the inlin source map - 'eval-source-map' devtool to generate the source maps. Changing it to 'source-map' which generates source maps as separate files enabled the breakpoints to work.

Comment: can you post your webpack.config.js ?